# DataFrame groupby and rolling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have the following test DataFrame to groupby id and calculate the price momentum over a rolling 2-day period:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['202211', '202211', '202211', '202212', '202212', '202212', '202213', '202213', '202213']
df['id'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
df['price'] = [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20]
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d')
df.sort_values(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)
df
```

```
            id  price
date        
2022-01-01  a   10
2022-01-02  a   15
2022-01-03  a   20
2022-01-01  b   10
2022-01-02  b   15
2022-01-03  b   20
2022-01-01  c   10
2022-01-02  c   15
2022-01-03  c   20
```

to get the price momentum of a 2 day rolling window per id, I found two solutions, which are 'momentum' and 'momentum2' in the following code. 'momentum' is what I use on my real dataset as it is a much faster computation and I am handling roughly 2 million rows in my df.

```
rolled = df.groupby('id').rolling(2)
df['momentum'] = rolled.sum().sort_values(['id', 'date'])['price'].values
df['momentum2'] = df.groupby('id')['price'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum())
df
```

```
           id  price  momentum  momentum2
date                                     
2022-01-01  a     10       NaN        NaN
2022-01-02  a     15      25.0       25.0
2022-01-03  a     20      35.0       35.0
2022-01-01  b     10       NaN        NaN
2022-01-02  b     15      25.0       25.0
2022-01-03  b     20      35.0       35.0
2022-01-01  c     10       NaN        NaN
2022-01-02  c     15      25.0       25.0
2022-01-03  c     20      35.0       35.0
```

Here on the test df it works perfectly fine as expected. On my real dataset however (using the 'momentum' method) it seems to be buggy and for many id's I already have momentum values for the first observations, where NaN would be expected. It seems like the matching of rolled doesn't work correctly even though it has been sorted in the same manner as the df.
What could be the reason?
Are there any other options to do this efficiently?

Comment: please provide at least parts of your real dataset to see why code is failing.... I think groupby rolling sum is the best way to go in this case.

Comment: I actually did find another method to ensure that that rolled.sum() is matched correctly to the original df. I am transforming rolled to a df and then join it to the original one. It seems fine for now!

Comment: Updated my message.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['momentum'] = df.groupby('id')['price'].transform(lambda y: y.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum())
```

Output

```
           id  price  momentum
date                          
2022-01-01  a     10        10
2022-01-02  a     15        25
2022-01-03  a     20        35
2022-01-01  b     10        10
2022-01-02  b     15        25
2022-01-03  b     20        35
2022-01-01  c     10        10
2022-01-02  c     15        25
2022-01-03  c     20        35
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is searching for. He wants to have a 2-day-view of the price, so für example for id a at the 03/01/2022 the sum has to be 35 (01/01 will be ignored) which isn't the case for `cumsum()`

Comment: @Rabinzel Now everything is as it should be, why do I have a minus?

Comment: Yes, at first I incorrectly made the code on the cumulative amount and because of this I was given a minus. Some time ago I found a solution and fixed the code. Needed a rolling sum of two days, and remove the empty values in the first day. As far as I understand, the question was more about how to remove NaN.

Comment: had a close look at it again. you have a point with the difference of NaN's compared to no NaN's in your approach. sorry that it took me so long :) would be nice to see by OP if this was actually the solution @jan.

Comment: An empty value appeared on the first day, since the moving average is counted for two days. That's why 'min_periods=1' is needed.Oh, well, of course.
You think I'm here from a good life answer. To be honest, I've been living in hell for 9 years and trying to get out somehow.